# function in a loop - JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, loops, while-loop

I tried to search a solution of my problem on StackOverflow but I didn't found. 
I'm working on a script which wasn't made by me. The person who worked on it didn't use loop at all in JQuery. So I'm trying to re-write the code with loops.

At the beggining, it was like this :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    width: 550,
      autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "dialog_style1",
    open: function() {
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click",function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        })
    }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open");
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
    width: 550,
      autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "dialog_style1",
    open: function() {
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click",function(){
            $("#dialog1").dialog("close");
        })
    }
    });

    $( "#opener1" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open");
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
    width: 550,
      autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "dialog_style1",
    open: function() {
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click",function(){
            $("#dialog2").dialog("close");
        })
    }
    });

    $( "#opener2" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open");
    });
  });
```

So it's the same function for different objects. Actually, there is 10 more time the same code ^^. That's why I tried to use a loop: while. So I rewrite the whole code to obtain this one :

```
var i = 0 ;
while(i<12){

    $(function() {
        var dial = "";
        if(i != 0){ dial = "#dialog"+i; }else{ dial = "#dialog";}
        var opener = "";
        if(i != 0){ opener = "#opener"+i; }else{ opener = "#opener";}

        $(dial).dialog({
        width: 550,
          autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: "dialog_style1",
        open: function() {
            $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click",function(){
                $(dial).dialog("close");
            })
        }
        });

        $( opener ).click(function() {
          $( dial ).dialog( "open");
        });
    });

    i++;
}
```

I think it's going to be simple later to use loops. So I thought this would do the exact same instructions. The problem is that it doesn't work at all. I have no idea about solution to my code. Maybe it's due to a problem of dynamic created function in the while...

Thanks for reading and I wait for your help :)

Comment: You might want to submit a jsbin of the original working example and what you have tried. This is allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you should bind one `ready` event instead of twelve, and put the loop inside the event handler.

That will incidentally solve your problem with the variable. As you bound twelve event handlers in the loop, all those would run after the loop has ended, and `i` would have the value `12` for all of them. By running the code directly in the loop, the variable has the correct value for each item.

However, you still have the problem for the `dial` variable that you use in the `open` and `click` event handlers, so you need a function that creates a closure for that variable, so that each iteration in the loop has its own `dial` variable:

```
$(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++){

    var opener = i == 0 ? "#opener" : "#opener" + i;

    (function(dial){

      $(dial).dialog({
        width: 550,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: "dialog_style1",
        open: function() {
          $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click",function(){
            $(dial).dialog("close");
          })
        }
      });

      $( opener ).click(function() {
        $( dial ).dialog( "open");
      });

    })(i == 0 ? "#dialog" : "#dialog" + i)

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the $(function(){}) in the while loop. that is actually the $(document).ready(function(){}) shorthand, and that document ready is only triggered once. try to put the while inside the document ready part. see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code to have the loop *inside* of the function.

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    while(i<12){        
        #code
        i++;
    }
});
```

Also, I would heavily recommend setting `var i = 1` and saving all the `if (i == 0)`-statements. Unless those are actually needed? I'm not sure. In that case, changing the *#dialog*  to *#dialog0* in the html would be nice, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for your answers. I tried every solutions but the Guffa's one worked for me. I didn't thought those event handlers would run after the loop so thanks a bunch for your explications. :)
Problem solved!